# In App Purchase : Auto Renewable Subscription Flow

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase

I have integrated Monthly Subscription to my app, for this I am using auto renewable in app purchase. 
Everything is working fine with SandBox build, but I am facing two issues when testing the build via TestFlight.

1. After a successful purchase, app is still asking me to confirm my Apple ID password with message "***Enter password for Apple ID xxxxxx.xxxx.xx to verify iTunes account and allow this device to confirm purchases.***"
2. After deleting and re installing the app I am trying to buy the previous item, and app shows a popup saying ***"You are currently Subscribed .......... Manage. OK."*** When I tap on Ok, nothing happens. I think at this moment *"updatedTransactions"* delegate should be called with *TransactionStatePurchased* but nothing is happening. or May be something is happening but I don't know how to debug this in TestFlight build.

I have added the transaction observer to AppDelegate

```
/*
 * ----------------- FOLLOWING ARE OBSERVERS FOR PAYMENT TRANSACTION ----------------------------
 */


-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray<SKPaymentTransaction *> *)transactions
{

    NSLog(@"Count =  %lu",(unsigned long)transactions.count);
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
            {
                NSLog(@"1. Transaction is in Purchasing state");
                [self handlePurchasingStateFor:transaction withQueue:queue];
                break;
            }

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            {
                NSLog(@"2. Transaction is in Purchased state");
                [self handlePurchasedStateFor:transaction withQueue:queue];
                break;
            }

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            {

                NSString *failMsg = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Purchase failed with error: %@",transaction.error.localizedDescription];
                NSLog(@"3. Error Mesg - %@",failMsg);

                [self handleFailStateFor:transaction withQueue:queue];
                break;
            }

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            {
                NSLog(@"4. Transaction is Restored");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                [self handleRestoreStateFor:transaction withQueue:queue];
                break;
            }

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred:
            {
                NSLog(@"5. Transaction is deffered, waiting for parent approval");
                [self handleDefferedStateFor:transaction withQueue:queue];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

-(void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {

    if (queue.transactions.count > 0)
    {
        NSDictionary* userInfo = @{@"error": @"Subscription restored successfully."};
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:InAppServicerestoreSuccessful object:self userInfo:userInfo];
    }
    else
    {
        NSDictionary* userInfo = @{@"error": @"There is no product to restore."};
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:InAppServicerestoreFail object:self userInfo:userInfo];
    }

}

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSDictionary* userInfo = @{@"error": @"Restore failed, please try again later"};
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:InAppServicerestoreFail object:self userInfo:userInfo];
}



/*
 * ------------------------------ CUSTOM METHODS TO HANDLE IN APP STATUS -----------------------
 */


-(void)handlePurchasingStateFor:(SKPaymentTransaction*)transaction withQueue:(SKPaymentQueue*)queue {
    NSLog(@"User is attempting to purchase product id: %@",transaction.payment.productIdentifier);
}

-(void)handlePurchasedStateFor:(SKPaymentTransaction*)transaction withQueue:(SKPaymentQueue*)queue {
    NSLog(@"User purchased product id: %@",transaction.payment.productIdentifier);
    [queue finishTransaction:transaction];

    NSDictionary* userInfo = @{@"error": @"Purchase is successful, you are all set."};
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:InAppServicepurchaseSuccessful object:self userInfo:userInfo];
}

-(void)handleRestoreStateFor:(SKPaymentTransaction*)transaction withQueue:(SKPaymentQueue*)queue {
    NSLog(@"User restored product id: %@",transaction.payment.productIdentifier);
    [queue finishTransaction:transaction];
}

-(void)handleFailStateFor:(SKPaymentTransaction*)transaction withQueue:(SKPaymentQueue*)queue {
    NSLog(@"User failed to purchase product id: %@",transaction.payment.productIdentifier);
}

-(void)handleDefferedStateFor:(SKPaymentTransaction*)transaction withQueue:(SKPaymentQueue*)queue {
    NSLog(@"App is waiting for parental permission for product id : %@",transaction.payment.productIdentifier);
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: When are you adding the observer to the `SKPaymentQueue`? And does this problem exist in a non test flight build (ie. testing a debug version on a device)

Comment: @MobileBen I am adding the observer in the app delegate. This problem is in Test Flight build. In test flight build when I am re purchasing the subscription it's giving me this popup "You are currently subscribed" and then in UpdateTransaction observer I am getting, transaction state is Failed.

Comment: When you deleted the app and reinstalled (via TF), how long was the delay before you tried to repurchase?

Comment: @MobileBen it's somewhere around 1 to 1.5 minute not more than that.

Comment: The subscription *is still* active then. I believe you will actually get a Failed error in that case, because there is no re-purchase needed (I could be wrong). Non-TF doesn't do that?

Comment: Have you checked the error on it too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177940/already-purchased-subscriptions-in-storekit

Comment: I think monthly subscriptions renew every 5 minutes in Sandbox. If you delete and re-install the app quickly you'll still be subscribed - receipts are tied to your App Store account and persist after your app is deleted.